# Ruby Array#bsearch: operation and returning nil when value is not in Array

Tags: ruby, performance

What am I missing here?

(I would expect `array.bsearch_index { |x| x == 11 }` to equal **1**)

```
array = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

p array.bsearch_index { |x| x == 11 }
# => nil
p array.bsearch_index { |x| x == 15 }
# => 5

p array.bsearch { |x| x == 11 }
# => nil
p array.bsearch { |x| x == 15 }
# => 15
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Garrett Johnson:

> the important thing is
>   
> the block returns **false** for any element whose index is less than i, and
>   
>  the block returns **true** for any element whose index is greater than or equal to i.
>
> If your block returns a bool, it finds the lowest-indexed element that meets the condition.

```
array = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

p array.bsearch_index { |x| 11 - x }
# => 1
p array.bsearch_index { |x| 15 - x }
# => 5

p array.bsearch { |x| 11 - x }
# => 11
p array.bsearch { |x| 15 - x }
# => 15
```

this solution also handles cases when the value is not in the array

```
p array.bsearch_index { |x| 11.5 - x }
# nil
```

Comment: Where is that quote from? Who is Garrett Johnson?

Comment: I posted this question in a Slack group and Garrett gave the answer that I posted here. If there is a preferred method of attribution, I would like to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax does not seem to conform to the following from the docs:

> the block returns false for any element whose index is less than i,
>   and
>
> the block returns true for any element whose index is greater than or
>   equal to i.

This `i` will never exist in the block that you have supplied it with. For example, in the loop at element 11 (x = 1), the block will return false for both x < `i` and x > `i` and this remains true for every subsequent elements as well.

You'll need to modify the block to this instead:

```
array.bsearch { |x| x >= 11 } # 11
array.bsearch_index { |x| x >= 11 } # 1
```

In this case and with the same example, the block returns false for all elements with index < 1 and true for all elements with index >= 1

Comment: What I like about Garrett's solution is that it returns nil for values that are not in the array

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. That is the 2 modes of the bsearch function (find-any and find-minimum)